# Return select statement and out parameter from stored procedure simultaneously in C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

My SQL Server stored procedure returns a result set from a `SELECT` statement and has `output parameters`. When I call this one from C# (connection in made through `SqlConnection` class) I have a problem: the out parameter returns null. If I comment select statement in procedure than it gets proper result.

```
CREATE PROC test
    @Out INT OUT
AS
BEGIN
    SET @Out=4
    SELECT * FROM temp_table    
END
```

Does out parameter wait to select statement?

How to fix it?

Added ----->
@huMptyduMpty is right i mentioned only sql procedure for experiment. Now I show changed procedure and code from C# side.
I write this procedure.

```
CREATE PROC T_Proc
    @Count INT = NULL OUT
AS
BEGIN

SET @Count = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM T_Table AS tt)
--SELECT * FROM T_Table AS tt
END
```

and this one in C#

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=127.0.0.1;Initial Catalog=test;Integrated Security=True");

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("T_Proc", conn);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

SqlDataAdapter MyDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
MyDataAdapter.SelectCommand = cmd;

SqlParameter a1 = cmd.Parameters.Add("@Count", SqlDbType.Int);
a1.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

DataSet Mydataset = new DataSet();

conn.Open();
cmd.ExecuteReader();
textBox1.Text = a1.Value.ToString();
conn.Close();
```

In this situation T_Proc returns result correctly, but if I uncheck this snip from SQL procedure     **--SELECT * FROM T_Table AS tt** than @Count returns **null**

Comment: If you are manually setting `SET @Out=4` why use output parameter at all??

Comment: I suspect that you have oversimplified the code.  If `@out` is set to 4, it has the value of 4 regardless of any subsequent `select` statements (that do not reassign the value).

Comment: @huMptyduMpty I guess he's just trying to get it to work as an experiment

Comment: As you didn't show the C# code, nobody can just correct it. But just read this [blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/spike/archive/2009/05/07/a-simple-example-on-how-to-get-return-and-out-parameter-values-using-ado-net.aspx) you will have some insight

Comment: I added additional information in my post, check please

Comment: @tungi: You can't do that. why you need both output and select statement together??

Comment: @huMptyduMpty, because in select statement I want to return report records, and in Out parametr, count of this records

Comment: @tungi: Updated my answer, please check !!

Comment: @huMptyduMpty, Yes it'll work, but I have more complex situation. I fill this data in GridView, when I call procc it returns me only limit numbers of row, which is selected in Grid(20,50 or 150). So I can not get count in c# side.

Comment: @tungi: Sorry I didn't got you, but think you need total rowcount, and select statement together. Check the updated answer

Comment: @huMptyduMpty, this is code which I already have and works, but :) it is not acceptable for me for several reasons. Main reason is that, i save report return information in Model(I am using as  ASP. MVC). So I have to add new property to it, such as Count. This is not nice. So for me OUT parametr and select statment together will be best way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *can* get both a dataset and parameter values, you just need to switch the order: *first* the dataset, *then* the parameters.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.direction.aspx):

> Output, InputOut, and ReturnValue parameters returned by calling ExecuteReader cannot be accessed until you close the SqlDataReader.

Answer (score 0):

"*A SQL Server stored procedure that you can call is one that returns one or more OUT parameters, which are parameters that the stored procedure uses to return data back to the calling application.* "

Read more about [Using a Stored Procedure with Output Parameters](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378108.aspx)

So you can do something like

```
CREATE PROC test
    @Out INT OUT
AS
BEGIN       
    SELECT @Out = FieldName FROM temp_table    
END
```

I suggest you (which i prefer), not to use out put parameter if you going to select multiple columns. You can use a [SqlDataReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.aspx) from your `c#` code

Also have a look at [Stored Procedure, when to use Output parameter vs Return variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3815502/stored-procedure-when-to-use-output-parameter-vs-return-variable)

**Update**

To get the row count, just remove your output parameter and get the count from c# code

i.e.

```
var reader =  cmd.ExecuteReader();  
var rowCount = reader.Cast<object>().Count();
```

Not quite sure what you after

check this one

```
CREATE PROC T_Proc

AS
BEGIN
Declare @Count INT 
SET @Count = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM T_Table AS tt)

SELECT *, @Count as TotalCount
FROM T_Table AS tt
Where xxxx---condition if you need any

END
```

Comment: Note that that first (technet) link deals with the JDBC driver (=Java).