# Fail to retrieve the User Id from Database using Dapper

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, dapper

```
public int UserAuthentication(UsersViewModel users)
{
        DynamicParameters parameters = new DynamicParameters();
        parameters.Add("@UserName", users.UserName);
        parameters.Add("@Password", users.Password);
        parameters.Add("@UserID", dbType: DbType.Int32, direction: ParameterDirection.ReturnValue);

        connection();
        sqlConn.Open();

        var result =  sqlConn.Execute("usp_UserLoginValidation", parameters, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);            
        // int userid = SqlMapper.Query<UsersViewModel>(sqlConn, "usp_UserLoginValidation", parameters, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure).FirstOrDefault();
        int userid = parameters.Get<int>("@UserID");

        sqlConn.Close();            

        return userid;
}
```

Stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE usp_UserLoginValidation
    (@UserName varchar(50),
     @Password varchar(20),
     @UserID int = 100 OUT)
AS
BEGIN
    SET @UserID = (SELECT UserId FROM Users 
                   WHERE UserName = @UserName AND Password = @Password AND IsActive = 1)
    SELECT @UserID
END
```

I'm trying to get the `UserId` from the database table, when the user logs into the application. Executing the stored procedure in the database returns the `UserId` but it fails to fetch that info into a class using Dapper.

I tried the following approaches:

1. Using `Execute` method, userid value is 0.
2. Using `Query` method, expect value but it returns the model (commented code)

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your stored procedure uses an `OUT` parameter but your `@UserID` is declared as `ParameterDirection.ReturnValue`.

If you use `ParameterDirection.Output` it should work as expected.

Comment: Thanks..It worked. just a follow up question, when a query return a model instead  value.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3815502/stored-procedure-when-to-use-output-parameter-vs-return-variable/42125448 it should answer your question on when to use a return value vs. output parameters

Answer (score 1):

You just modify **SELECT @UserID => RETURN @UserID**. Then it will work as expected.
Hope to help, my friend :))

Comment: Thanks. It worked for Query method not when using Execute method.